# Why won't my alteryx R and Rstudio pull from the same package library?

Tags: r, alteryx, tidycensus

I am getting an error telling me I don't have packages when trying to use tidycensus in R/Alteryx. This works fine in Rstudio? Does anyone know how to change alteryx directory to match rstudio for calling packages?

```
[![library(tindycensus)
library(tigris)
Fl_blocks <- blocks("FL", year = 2010)
Fl_blocks_Alachua <- filter(Fl_blocks, COUNTYFP == "001")

# Output 2010 FL CB Data
write.Alteryx(Fl_blocks_Alachua, 1)][1]][1]
```

Comment: Alteryx installs R behind the scenes. You should be able to point R-studio at that install of R, and then things should be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is get the package paths in the *Alteryx* R tool and then control package installs in *RStudio* to make sure packages go into that path.

Avoiding having *Alteryx* `install.packages` has worked very well.